# Conditional add_filter for upload directory?

Tags: uploads, filters

I have a custom media upload button (in the standard post edit page, alongside the standard media upload button), and need to change the upload directory dynamically if this button is clicked - using add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'my_function').

This post & answer: [Conditional add_filter?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/conditional-add-filter)  seem to give the solution, but for some reason don't work for me - the additional parameter 'hexProtected' is not set & so add_filter is not called.

My code is below... am I doing something stupid or does the solution posted not work?!

```
<?php
/* Custom Upload Directory for protected posts */                                    

function hex_protected_media_button($context) {
    global $post;
    $media_button_image = 'http://www.example.com/wp-admin/images/media-button.png?ver=20111005';
    $media_button = ' %s' . '<a href="media-upload.php?post_id='.$post->ID.'&amp;TB_iframe=1&amp;hexProtected=1" class="thickbox"><img src="'.$media_button_image.'" /></a>';
    return sprintf($context, $media_button);
}

add_filter('media_buttons_context', 'hex_protected_media_button');                                                           
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'hex_pre_upload');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'hex_post_upload');

function hex_pre_upload($file){  
    if (isset($_GET['hexProtected'])) {
       add_filter('upload_dir', 'hex_custom_upload_dir');
    }
    return $file;
}

function hex_custom_upload_dir($path){      
    if(!empty($path['error'])) { return $path; } //error; do nothing.   
    $path['path'] = str_replace($path['subdir'], '/protected'.$path['subdir'], $path['path']);
    $path['url'] = str_replace($path['subdir'], '/protected'.$path['subdir'], $path['url']);        
    $path['subdir']  = '/protected';    
    return $path;
}

?>
```

Comment: What exact is "don't work for me"? Error? Notice? Warning? Debug output?

Comment: @kaiser - sorry!  Have updated the post - no error as such, the parameter just doesn't seem to be set.

Comment: Please add some [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question. Currently we can't help you, as the needed information isn't available.

Comment: @kaiser - when I turn wp_debug on, in the admin area I get two notices referencing the S2Member plugin I have installed (as far as I know unrelated):

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: cache_needs_updating in ../public_html/wp-content/plugins/s2member/includes/classes/cache.inc.php on line 97 and Notice: Undefined index: page in ../public_html/wp-content/plugins/s2member/includes/classes/admin-notices.inc.php on line 136

Comment: Let me know if there is anywhere else I should look... appreciate your help.

Comment: Please deactivate any plugin (aside from your custom code) and test your setup inside TwentyTen/*Eleven/*Twelve, so we know for sure what we're talking about. And please don't use any caching plugins during development. Caching successfully prevents getting any debug info.

Comment: @kaiser - thanks. I have created a new test site, with a vanilla WP install & TwentyEleven theme.  No plugins installed, wp_debug turned on.  I then added my code to functions.php to get my additional media upload button.  As previously, no errors/warnings/notices produced when I upload with this button.  But it still does not change the upload directory.

Comment: Also - just to confirm this works fine if I apply the add_filter to ALL media uploads. It's the conditional bit that doesn't work - if (isset($_GET['hexProtected'])) ... if I place the add_filter outside of that statement, it works as expected.

Comment: Append `?hexProtected` to the URl and see what happens.

Comment: @kaiser - sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  The link is already, for e.g., http://www.example.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=329&TB_iframe=1&hexProtected=1&width=640&height=676.  I've tried the hexProtected parameter with & without the 1, but no joy...

Comment: But a `var_dump( $_GET )` shows you all other args? Btw: Try `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @kaiser - bother, no! a var_dump($_GET) in my wp_handle_upload_prefilter function shows an empty array (when image is being uploaded).  So presumably that means that using $_GET is no good?

Comment: Try `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid.  And a var_dump ($_REQUEST) gives the following: array(6) { ["name"]=> string(30) "test.jpg" ["post_id"]=> string(3) "329" ["_wpnonce"]=> string(10) "b6253e8135" ["type"]=> string(4) "file" ["tab"]=> string(4) "type" ["short"]=> string(1) "1" } 385

Answer (score 5):

I know it's been a while, but I wanted to offer a solution, if only for those who come across this question via Google.

The issue is with the order of the parameters in the query string when you build the URL for the media uploader. My experience is that any parameters that come after 'TB_iframe=1' are ignored, so you want to put your custom values before this. I haven't seen this documented (and haven't explored core to see why the parameters are handled this way), but can't think of any good reason for it--I probably spent an hour tearing my hair out before I discovered the issue.

I also haven't tried this in 3.5 yet. With all the changes to the media uploader it's possible that this has been addressed.

Comment: The `TB_iframe` behavior you mentioned is Thickbox: ["Add all other query parameters before the TB_iframe parameters. Everything after the "TB" is removed from the URL."](http://thickbox.net/)